# Save page position (vertical scroll in browser ... ) after clicking button or some other action

Tags: asp.net

Can I save a page position in browser after clicking button or some other actions (after PostBack)

I need it on Page Change event in my DBGrid like on msdn.microsoft.com - when I change Tab C# -> C++ for example it doesn't refresh whole page and I still being on same position in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by specifying MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the page directive of the ASPX file.

for example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MySite.MyPage" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Enjoy,

Koby

Answer (score 1):

Going back to my 1.1 projects, I have done this through a hidden text box and some JavaScript.

First, you need to track the position of the scroll bars on the page.

```
document.body.onscroll = function(){
       document.getElementById('hiddentextboxid').value =                         
                  document.body.scrollLeft + '|' + document.body.scrollTop;
 }
```

where hiddentextboxid is the ClientID of a hidden text box you placed on the page.

Second, you need to reset the scroll position when the page is again displayed.  My first step in doing this was to emit a javascript function to reset the position:

```
        string sPosition = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[hiddentextboxid];
        if (sPosition != null && sPosition != "")
        {
            string[] sPos = sPosition.Split("|".ToCharArray());
            StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
            strScript.Append("<script language='Javascript'>\r\n");
            strScript.Append("function ProcessScroll(){\r\n");
            strScript.Append("    window.scrollTo(" + sPos[0] + ", " + sPos[1] + ");\r\n");
            strScript.Append("}\r\n");
            strScript.Append("</script>");
            if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "Scroll"))
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Scroll", strScript.ToString());
        }
```

I then had this chunk of code to call that javascript function when appropriate:

```
            sScript.Append("<script language='javascript'>\r\n");
        sScript.Append("document.body.onload = function() {\r\n");

        if (Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "Scroll"))
        {
            sScript.Append("    ProcessScroll();\r\n");
            sScript.Append("}\r\n");
            sScript.Append("</script>");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ProcessOnLoad", sScript.ToString());
        }
```

I believe there are some newer and slightly more efficient ways to do portions of this.  However, I haven't used this code in quite a while because I typically do Ajax postbacks now to avoid this problem.